# Longer duration bounties?

Tags: feature-request, bounty

A user may have a particularly tricky question, that he/she'd like to award a large bounty for, that could also be kept open for a longer period of time.

This increased period would be optional and subject to a cap proportional to the size of the bounty.

e.g. 200 points - max 2 weeks bounty (1 week extra)

300 points - max 3 weeks,

and so on.

This would make sense because some questions may be answerable only by a niche audience, and increasing the bounty period **increases the probability of the question being found and answered by a person of just the *right*, *niche* expertise**. A longer bounty period would also allow for adequate research to be done to answer particularly tricky questions. (the research itself may only take a couple of hours, but the answerer may only be able to make time for it, say on a weekend)

P.S: I'm asking because I have an open question *right now* that could use a longer-period bounty, and the only way I can achieve this effect in the current system is by:

1. Starting a bounty at a low level, say 100, for 1 week.

2. Keep opening new bounties for as long as the question goes unanswered.

3. Once a good answer is provided, award extra points to the answerer with a larger new bounty. (if that's possible).

Obviously this involves a LOT of wastage of points, and doesn't provide the full intended incentive to the answerers up-front. So a large bounty value COMBINED with a long bounty period seems to make a lot of sense.

Comment: Just set a new bounty when the previous one ends. I don't see *any* point in complicating that system. It is now clear to anyone familiar with the system how long the bounty will last, and everyone gets the *same exposure*.

Comment: Yes, I just mentioned that it's not a viable approach, reasons mentioned in the post.

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178925/allow-high-reward-bounties-to-be-longer-bounties.

Comment: It is already too long.  Fundamental problem is that SO users don't close their question when they get the answer they need.  Teaching them to be better citizens is a long shot, extending the bounty period just makes it worse.  Just assign another bounty.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/240703/165773

Comment: I didn't think to search on Meta.SE for this. I see the idea has got a bit of traction. As long as it happens (hopefully soon), I'm happy.

Comment: Just re-read the post on meta.se and saw the actual date! I suppose the problem is naturally only more visible and important to those ASKING obscure questions, and therefore only seemingly important to a small, obscure section of the population. :(

Comment: @Hans Passant, People who willingly use the bounty system - I think, are bound to be serious users of SO who are also serious about marking the right answers as accepted, etc. People who don't care about a QUICK answer, but a QUALITY answer, and therefore likely to put up a LONG, HIGH-VALUE bounty, are even more so. I think the problem is definitely being seen through the wrong lens here.

Comment: @Dev: I've seen lots of users with minimal rep (a couple hundred) post a bounty to try to get an answer to poor questions. There's no correlation between bounty and the dedication of the people posting them. I've flagged questions on several occasions where the poster has asked an off-topic question (recommendations/requests for discussion) and placed a bounty on it to keep it from being closed by normal means, for instance.

Comment: Hm. That makes sense. Feature for one, exploit for another. But preventing exploits cannot (in most cases) be the only reason for vetoing features. The utility of the feature itself has been called into question and that's a bigger negative. Please see my absolute last comments on @Servy's answer, for a summary. Thank you for the insight on misuse!

Answer (score 3):

When you post a bounty you're *paying for the additional attention to your post*.  If you want to have twice as much attention in the form of twice as much time on the featured list, then you're going to need to pay for multiple bounties.

Keep in mind that having bounties last two or three weeks means that there will be many more active bounties at any given point in time, which will reduce the attention that *all* bounties get while they are active.

Comment: Paying more is EXACTLY my point. Combined with the fact that putting up a banner that says "300 points" and keeping it up for 3 weeks has a MUCH higher chance of success than 3 separate 100-point bounties. And the SNR in both cases is exactly the same. Note that a lower-point bounty would still have lower exposure - only 1 week - so the SNR will only change in favor of the tougher, higher-bounty deserving questions, which I think is a good thing.

Comment: I wanted to avoid the meta effect, but considering the problem seems to be so obscure, let me share an example. Consider this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25353838/xcode6-not-enabling-development-on-ios8-iphone-device. Do you see anyone investing the time to debug/understand the ROOT of this obviously flaky, but nonetheless annoying and critically productivity-killing issue, if only a 100 points were on offer? This is a high-bounty question, if it has to have a chance at a meaningful answer at all.

Comment: Secondly, the chances of the question being found by someone actually capable of understanding the root-cause within a "normal" time-frame is really small, and the chances of an answer received within a week being GOOD, are even less so. I'd want to wait for at least 2-3 weeks for a good answer, and award 2-300 points for an answer that's actually worth it.

Comment: Or consider this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25822142/why-is-xcode-flaky-about-throwing-duplicate-symbol-errors I care less about this one, but this such an obscure issue, that if important enough, it can deserve a high bounty and require a few weeks to actually get the attention of someone who CAN debug it. (Note: There may be some relatively simple ways to debug this second question, I simply didn't have the time and chose to rely on the wisdom of the community instead - but the point, hopefully, still remains. Obscurity demands higher points, for longer).

Comment: @DevKanchen Yes, if you're able to have a question bountied for several weeks while everyone else is stuck on just a week then your question is going to get quite a lot more visibility.  When most all bounties end up getting three weeks of visibility then everyone is pretty much back in the same boat.

Comment: But it's not just about the question being visible, it's also about it intersecting with the RIGHT users. For obscure questions, the probability of intersecting with the RIGHT user is very low, and increases with the duration of exposure. The long-bounty questions are not MEANT to be exposed to the 80% for 3 weeks, but hit that rare 20 (or 2%) who happens to come across your question by CHANCE, the chance improved by being visible as a bounty. Also not ALL bounties will be 3 weeks or so. They will be proportional to size. I'm not aware of the bounty distribution but imagine 50/100 most common

Comment: @DevKanchen You say you don't want to expose the question to a wide  audience for a long period of time, *but that's exactly what is going to happen*.  When you have a particularly obscure question that very few people in the world can ever answer then getting answers is obviously hard.  A bounty cannot necessarily solve that problem in the general case.  You seem to be considering your one exact situation and not considering the ramifications of a change like this on every other situation involving bounties.

Comment: Fair enough, but isn't the point of a bounty two-fold, one being - as mentioned in some places - getting quick answers to questions. And the second, that arises naturally from the design of the bounties, regardless of the original intention, being to reward answers to particularly tough questions, and get attention to obscure ones? Bounties ARE a special case, not for your everyday questions, but for ones that NEED special attention, either out of personal need or the NEED OF THE QUESTION itself. And I genuinely feel they will only be better served by more flexibility in the system.

Comment: @DevKanchen Bounties are not there to get fast answers to questions, no.  Yes, getting answers to hard questions, or obscure questions, (particularly the former) are goals.  Another goal is to encourage higher quality answers to a question that currently only has mediocre or low quality answers.  There are still more, see the bounty page to see them.  Once again, keep in mind that if your goal is to get more attention to your question, that goal is not necessarily met if all/most of the other bounties end up being extended in duration as well.

Comment: I might have misworded my original comment to which you responded - I didn't mean the exposure to 80% won't happen, but that they won't matter in terms of getting a reasonable answer. What will matter is that it hit that other 20%, or 2%. And to achieve that a long exposure is required. This naturally means adding to the noise for the 80%, you're right about that. But considering it's only for the high-bounty questions, I don't think the disturbance would be much. If, say, 200-point bounties are very common, then have the multiple-week extension only for the 500-pointers and so on.

Comment: Having week-extensions only for the top few percentile of bounties - whether that is 500 points or much more than that - will keep SNR low while making bounties more useful for obscure questions. I don't see how a graded system - which is what I've recommended, the values of course depending on the actual data - would increase noise as you say. SNR is the goal of a graded system.

Comment: @DevKanchen If you want to start talking about bounties of amounts over 500, or only the very top percent of bounties, then you can already accomplish this by simply using multiple sequential bounties.  You'll have to spend rep in the top few percent of bounty submitters, but you can do it.

Comment: "many more active bounties at any given point in time...will reduce the attention that all bounties get" - not if the points thresholds (that make a bounty eligible to be extended in the first place) are high enough, and graded, as mentioned in my original question.

Comment: @DevKanchen At which point you can accomplish those same goals by just using sequential bounties, as mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: I think the fundamental point of difference here is, I'm thinking of being able to award a high bounty incentive to the answerer. For most "budget" users like me, this won't be possible with repeat bounties. And a low-bounty ultra-hard or ultra-obscure question, even if repeated for several weeks, may not be attractive to an answerer.

Comment: @DevKanchen That is all true.  It would still all be true if your proposed feature were implemented.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62781/discussion-between-dev-kanchen-and-servy).

Comment: As discussed in chat the proposal is really about extracting maximum VALUE out of points spent, whether it's in serial bounties, or in one big, multi-week bounty. It would take some effort to figure out the right balance between too few points for multi-week and so many that it's useful only for high-rep users anyway, who can already afford high-value serial bounties. This feature request is thus only relevant for low-med rep users who want to use large bounties. Since there isn't much noise from  such a sector at this point, it doesn't seem to be a pressing need. We move on.

Comment: Thank you @Servy for the long, untiring debate!